# GCC inline assembly error: junk `(%ebp)+4' after expression

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly

I'm trying to compile inline assembly (with **-fasm-blocks**) which works in **MSVC**, but **GCC** gives me the **junk `(%ebp)+4' after expression** error... Why won't it accept the syntax and how should I fix this?

```
uint64_t _tmp = 100;

_asm
{
     //_tmp value may be changed
     //...
     cmp dword ptr _tmp, 100 // Ok
     jnae temp
     cmp dword ptr _tmp + 4, 50 // It seems GCC doesn't want to accept _tmp + 4
     jnae temp
     //...
     temp:
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change it to:

```
cmp dword ptr [_tmp + 4], 50
```

Comment: Thanks, man! This gives me the 'Addressing mode too complex, will consume an extra register' warning, but at least it compiles :)